# Tensorflow Serving C++ Syntax

Tags: c++, tensorflow-serving

Now, I'm studying Tensorflow Serving and try to create a Custom Servable.

So, I read the code about hashmap_source_adaptor (This is example code in Tensorflow Serving).

But, there is some code, i can't understand.

```
HashmapSourceAdapter::HashmapSourceAdapter(
    const HashmapSourceAdapterConfig& config)
    : SimpleLoaderSourceAdapter<StoragePath, Hashmap>(
          [config](const StoragePath& path, std::unique_ptr<Hashmap>* hashmap) {
            return LoadHashmapFromFile(path, config.format(), hashmap);
          },
          // Decline to supply a resource footprint estimate.
          SimpleLoaderSourceAdapter<StoragePath,
                                    Hashmap>::EstimateNoResources()) {}

HashmapSourceAdapter::~HashmapSourceAdapter() { Detach(); }
```

What is [config] means in line 4?

Give me a idea or hint to search about that.

The origin code is in this link. and I can't understand line 70.
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/servables/hashmap/hashmap_source_adapter.cc#L70

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[config]` is a capture list for the lambda expression. Since it's not specified otherwise, it captures `config` by value. This copies whatever `config` refers to, and makes it visible inside the lambda.

Capturing `config` is needed, because the code in the lambda expression uses `config`:

> return LoadHashmapFromFile(path, **config**.format(), hashmap);

For `config` to mean something inside the lambda expression, it has to be captured. In particular, a lambda expression is basically a short-cut for creating a class. Anything in the capture list (that's actually used inside the lambda expression) becomes a parameter that's passed to the ctor for that class (and the body of the lambda expression becomes the body of an overload of `operator()()` for that class).